# Discord.js post a message with dynamic content

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

Is it possible to post a message with a bot using Discord.JS where the message's content can be dynamic and vary based on the member who views the message?

For example, the message is sent to a channel but displays different content based on which user has entered the channel to view it.

Something like this:

Message content: "Hello!"

User A in channel sees: "Hi!"
User B in channel sees: "Howdy!"
etc.

Essentially, is there a way for the message content to be programmable and make it so that you can choose to have a different content displayed for some members based on their User ID?

For context, I want to display images in the server and each image needs to contain a watermark with the user's username to prevent sharing elsewhere. Currently I have a system where the user needs to be click a button to have an image generated for them, but I am hoping to achieve the same without the user needing to interact with the bot.

Comment: Do you mean the *same message* has different watermarks? Or only a specific watermark per message?

Comment: @DarshanB Yeah that's what I mean, so the same message is sent but it displays varying content based on the viewing member

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you might have to try a different approach. The best I could think of would be to use ephemeral responses on button click.

Comment: No, not possible. Either have the bot dm each member, or use interaction responses

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't, you could give different response choices when the command was retrieved, but each user would see the same thing if it wasn't ephemeral. But you could do a

```
if(interaction.user.id == 'id from some user'){
    […]
}
```

to make a reply specific to the user.

Comment: That is what I am already doing, I was looking to see if I can achieve the same without the users having to make an interaction first, to reduce friction for the users having to make an interaction every time

Comment: No actually it dont excist any possibilty to do this.

Comment: This answer would require the user to interact with the message before it was edited/modified.